# Separator Retention Mode in perl split()

Tags: perl, split

```
split /PATTERN/,EXPR
```

I read the following in a book,

> When you use a pattern in **split**, be sure to avoid memory parantheses
>   in the pattern since these trigger seperator retention mode.

I can't seem to find the documentation which explains this in detail. Could someone please explain **Seperator Retention Mode** and its possible usage briefly?

Comment: be cautious of that book - "Seperator [sic] Retention Mode" and "memory parentheses" look to me like terms the author has just made up; if there's a lot of that, you will have a hard time understanding other people using more widespread terms.

Comment: "separator retention mode" gets ~100 result on Google. Many are from our very own brian d. foy.

Comment: Unfortunately, *none* of those seem to point to the relevant perldoc page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is documented in [`perldoc -f split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) towards the end (in-code commentary is my own):

> If the `PATTERN` contains capturing groups, then for each separator,
>   an additional field is produced for each substring captured by a group
>   (in the order in which the groups are specified, as per
>   backreferences); if any group does not match, then it captures the
>   `undef` value instead of a substring. Also, note that any such
>   additional field is produced whenever there is a separator (that is,
>   whenever a split occurs), and such an additional field does **not** count
>   towards the `LIMIT`. Consider the following expressions evaluated in
>   list context (each returned list is provided in the associated
>   comment):
>
> ```
> split(/-|,/, "1-10,20", 3)       # ('1', '10', '20')
>                                  # No retention, '-', ',' consumed
>
> split(/(-|,)/, "1-10,20", 3)     # ('1', '-', '10', ',', '20')
>                                  # Split on and retain '-' or ','
>                                  # 5 elements returned
>
> split(/-|(,)/, "1-10,20", 3)     # ('1', undef, '10', ',', '20')
>                                  # undef because '-' matches
>
> split(/(-)|,/, "1-10,20", 3)     # ('1', '-', '10', undef, '20')
>                                  # undef because ',' matches
>
> split(/(-)|(,)/, "1-10,20", 3)   # ('1', '-', undef, '10', undef, ',', '20')
>                                  # one match per capturing group. (-) matches -, but
>                                  # (,) returns undef on trying to match -.
>                                  # 7 elements (!)
> ```

---

So, two interesting quirks that may catch out the unwary:

- The generation of `undef`s in list context whenever a capturing group does not match, but something else in `PATTERN` does
- You might split with a capture group, specifying `LIMIT` as `$n`, and the resultant list has more than `$n` elements

Answer (score 1):

It means that if you use a regex with parentheses that generates back references, then the matched separators will be retained, and returned in the list, along with the split values.

Comment: Should that read "a regex with parentheses that generates back references" or "any regex with capturing group(s)?"

Comment: Spell it "Raymond Luxury Yacht". I'm personnaly unaware of a way to generate backlinks without using parens. But I'm willing to learn.